# Issue About Resource Dictionary in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, resourcedictionary

This is the first time I used the Resource Dictionary, I create new Resource Dictionary :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,6,0" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In my windows (where I want to used the style) I declared :

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="MyDictionary"
                    Source="/AlrakizaTouch;component/MyDictionary.xaml"/>
```

My question is how can I used the style with `datagrid` control, I tried this :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgItemsReceipt"
          CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridCell}"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ocItemsinInvoice,Mode=TwoWay}"
          Margin="10,-1,0,176" Width="412" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          RowHeight="34" CurrentCellChanged="dgItemsReceipt_CurrentCellChanged"
          SelectionMode="Single" ColumnHeaderHeight="50"
          Foreground="#FFCFCFCF" BorderBrush="#FFE8E8E8">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But give me this error "The Resource `DataGridCell` could not be resolved".

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge your dictionary within windows resource dictionary

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="/AlrakizaTouch;component/MyDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Why merge ? There's just one dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sceptic about nit's answer. I think your problem was :

```
CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridCell}"
```

instead of

```
CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type DataGridCell}}"
```

Also, you don't have to merge just one dictionary, you can just do :

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="/AlrakizaTouch;component/MyDictionary.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Franssu, Thank you, but I Tried both format they didn't work. when I used nit's solution it work for me. any way thank you so much for your advice and I'll try it another time without merge.

Comment: @AbdusalamElsherif What I don't understand is where did you add the dictionary in the first place if not under <Window.Resources> ?

Comment: I don't understand you what you mean ?

Comment: I mean : that's not nit's answer and merged dictionaries that fixed your problem. The problem with your code was the lack of the x:Type markup extension when setting the resourcekey.